# Responsive Menu - HREF Not Clickable

Tags: jquery, menu, responsive-design

The following code works for the menu, but for some reason the `href` links are not clickable. Hovering over them shows the URL .

Struggling to understand would this be caused by the code below?

```
$(window).on('resize',menu);
    $(document).bind("ready", function() {
        menu();
    });

    function menu() {

        if(window.innerWidth < 989) {

            // Responsive Menu

            $('nav ul li').toggle(function() {   
                $(this).children("ul").slideDown(500).addClass("open"); 
            },
            function() {
                $(this).children("ul").slideUp(500).removeClass("open");    
            });

        }

    };
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: None unfortunately...

Comment: I'm guessing you've got another event handler (not in the code above) bound to these anchors that includes `event.stopPropagation()`, `event.preventDefault()` or `return false`, which is preventing the click event from bubbling up through the DOM and triggering the default browser navigation behavior based on the anchor's `href` attribute. You might consider inspecting one of these anchors in the DOM inspector of your favorite browser and digging into the "Event Listeners"  section to see if you can spot any misbehaving event handlers.